# jQuery Mobile popup won't show after page navigation, only shows after hard refresh, or returning to same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

**What I have**

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.4.4. I've added a gear button on each header that will open a small popup to navigate among 'Logout' and 'Account Settings'.

**What I want to happen**

I want this popup to show up on every page that it is clicked on, using the same code for each page

**The problem**

On the home page (call it page A) I have this gear button. When I click on it, the popup will appear just fine. I then click on account settings (call it page B). Once page B has loaded, the gear is also there, but does not open the popup like page A does. If I *refresh* page B, the gear popup will work, but once I navigate back to page A (via the home button) the gear no longer works until I refresh.

Video of the described scenario situation: http://screencast.com/t/34ZrYyc4Rp2T

**Code**

Just the header and popup html (same on both pages)

```
<body>
 <table id="top" border=0 >
 <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 33%"/>
    <col style="width: 33%"/>
    <col style="width: 33%"/>
 </colgroup>
 <tr>
     <td align="left">
         <a href="javascript:window.history.back();" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">Back</a>
     </td>
     <td id="tdTitle" align="middle" style="padding-top:10px;">
         <h2>Home</h2>
     </td>
     <td align="right">
         <a href="Home.php" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">Home</a>
         <a href='#settingsPopup' data-rel='popup' data-transition='pop' data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">Settings</a>
     </td>

 </tr>
</table>  
 <div data-role='popup' id='settingsPopup' >
<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' style='min-width:210px;'>
    <li data-role='list-divider'>
        Settings                
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='AccountSettings.php'>Account Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='Logout.php'>Logout</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**What I think is happening**

I've read that this issue may be because the ID of the popups are the same? Which doesn't make sense because they are two different pages.

It could also be the case that the popup is populated within the `<div role="page">`

lapieuvre's issue (in reply to the similar issue at hand) here is the exact same scenario: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/popup-open-not-working-after-navigate-next-page

**Any feedback is greatly appreciated**

Comment: Because the ID of the popups are the same. It does make sense if you understand the way jQuery Mobile works, it fetches the HTML partials via AJAX, making sort of a Single Page Application.

Comment: @SameerShemna So either I set the anchor tags with `data-ajax=false` or I change the IDs for each popup.

Comment: It is best to use AJAX thats the whole idea, just change the IDs preferably to have a prefix for you to identify its parent page, thats the way to go. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @SameerShemna, if you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing up the answer:

Because the ID of the popups are the same. It does make sense if you understand the way jQuery Mobile works, it fetches the HTML partials via AJAX, making sort of a Single Page Application.

It is best to use AJAX thats the whole idea, just change the IDs preferably to have a prefix for you to identify its parent page, thats the way to go. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I was researching the same issue when I found this post. What worked for me was placing the popup div in an external toolbar: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/toolbar-external/

"Toolbars not within a page will not be pulled into the DOM during Ajax navigation." That way you won't have multiple divs with the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the OP for posting this, as this problem caused me much puzzlement over a couple of days.  Actually my issue was slightly different because the same page was showing this behavior, so a page-related ID would not solve the problem.

However, along the same lines as the first responder, I use a random number as part of the popup ID, which solves the problem in a similar manner.